# Argument Error While Trying to Make Inference With TensorRT

Tags: python, tensorflow, inference, tensorrt

I am trying to convert a Tensorflow model into TensorRT. I have a GAN and I have saved models for each network. I have three different models. You can see the graphs of the models below. 
Process Kp Driving:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:
signature_def['__saved_model_init_op']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['__saved_model_init_op'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: NoOp
  Method name is: 
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['adapt_movement_scale'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: ()
        name: serving_default_adapt_movement_scale:0
    inputs['kp_driving'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 10, 2)
        name: serving_default_kp_driving:0
    inputs['kp_driving_initial'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 10, 2)
        name: serving_default_kp_driving_initial:0
    inputs['kp_driving_initial_jacobian'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 10, 2, 2)
        name: serving_default_kp_driving_initial_jacobian:0
    inputs['kp_driving_jacobian'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 10, 2, 2)
        name: serving_default_kp_driving_jacobian:0
    inputs['kp_source'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 10, 2)
        name: serving_default_kp_source:0
    inputs['kp_source_jacobian'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 10, 2, 2)
        name: serving_default_kp_source_jacobian:0
    inputs['use_relative_jacobian'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: ()
        name: serving_default_use_relative_jacobian:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['jacobian'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 10, 2, 2)
        name: PartitionedCall:0
    outputs['value'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 10, 2)
        name: PartitionedCall:1
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
Defined Functions:
  Function Name: '__call__'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          kp_driving: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='kp_driving')
        Argument #2
          kp_driving_jacobian: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10, 2, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='kp_driving_jacobian')
        Argument #3
          kp_driving_initial: TensorSpec(shape=(1, 10, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='kp_driving_initial')
        Argument #4
          kp_driving_initial_jacobian: TensorSpec(shape=(1, 10, 2, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='kp_driving_initial_jacobian')
        Argument #5
          kp_source: TensorSpec(shape=(1, 10, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='kp_source')
        Argument #6
          kp_source_jacobian: TensorSpec(shape=(1, 10, 2, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='kp_source_jacobian')
        Argument #7
          use_relative_jacobian: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='use_relative_jacobian')
        Argument #8
          adapt_movement_scale: TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='adapt_movement_scale')
  Function Name: 'convex_hull_area'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          X: TensorSpec(shape=(1, 10, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='X')
```

Kp Detector:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:
signature_def['__saved_model_init_op']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['__saved_model_init_op'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: NoOp
  Method name is: 
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['img'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 256, 256, 3)
        name: serving_default_img:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['jacobian'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: PartitionedCall:0
    outputs['value'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: PartitionedCall:1
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
Defined Functions:
  Function Name: '__call__'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          img: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='img')
```

Generator:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:
signature_def['__saved_model_init_op']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['__saved_model_init_op'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: NoOp
  Method name is: 
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['kp_driving'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 10, 2)
        name: serving_default_kp_driving:0
    inputs['kp_driving_jacobian'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 10, 2, 2)
        name: serving_default_kp_driving_jacobian:0
    inputs['kp_source'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 10, 2)
        name: serving_default_kp_source:0
    inputs['kp_source_jacobian'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 10, 2, 2)
        name: serving_default_kp_source_jacobian:0
    inputs['source_image'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 256, 256, 3)
        name: serving_default_source_image:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['prediction'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: PartitionedCall:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
Defined Functions:
  Function Name: '__call__'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          source_image: TensorSpec(shape=(1, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='source_image')
        Argument #2
          kp_driving: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='kp_driving')
        Argument #3
          kp_driving_jacobian: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10, 2, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='kp_driving_jacobian')
        Argument #4
          kp_source: TensorSpec(shape=(1, 10, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='kp_source')
        Argument #5
          kp_source_jacobian: TensorSpec(shape=(1, 10, 2, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='kp_source_jacobian')
```

After creating models like this, I try to infer with them. Kp_detector works fine. However, the others are not working. kp_detector needs one input but generator and process_kp_driving have multiple inputs. You can see the error output below for generator. The output for process_kp_detector is also the same with different arguments.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bugrahan/miniconda3/envs/prod/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1683, in _call_impl
    cancellation_manager)
  File "/home/bugrahan/miniconda3/envs/prod/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1709, in _call_with_flat_signature
    len(args)))
TypeError: signature_wrapper(kp_driving, kp_driving_jacobian, kp_source, kp_source_jacobian, source_image) takes 0 positional arguments but 5 were given
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 43, in <module>
    test()
  File "test.py", line 37, in test
    labeling = infer(source, kp_driving, kp_driving_jacobian, kp_source, kp_source_jacobian)
  File "/home/bugrahan/miniconda3/envs/prod/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1669, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/bugrahan/miniconda3/envs/prod/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1685, in _call_impl
    raise structured_err
  File "/home/bugrahan/miniconda3/envs/prod/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1679, in _call_impl
    cancellation_manager)
  File "/home/bugrahan/miniconda3/envs/prod/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1756, in _call_with_structured_signature
    self._structured_signature_check_missing_args(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/bugrahan/miniconda3/envs/prod/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1777, in _structured_signature_check_missing_args
    ", ".join(sorted(missing_arguments))))
TypeError: signature_wrapper(*, kp_source, source_image, kp_source_jacobian, kp_driving_jacobian, kp_driving) missing required arguments: kp_driving, kp_driving_jacobian, kp_source, kp_source_jacobian, source_image
```

The question is that I am doing the same thing while converting models but why I get this error? How can I specify input arguments for other models? Am I allowed to use TensorRT with only one input argument? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I found the solution after posting this question. When calling the inference function, we need to call it like this
`infer(kp_driving=kp_driving, kp_driving_jacobian=kp_driving_jacobian, kp_driving_initial=kp_driving_initial, kp_driving_initial_jacobian=kp_driving_initial_jacobian, kp_source=kp_source,
                       kp_source_jacobian=kp_source_jacobian, use_relative_jacobian=use_relative_jacobian, adapt_movement_scale=adapt_movement_scale)`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).